# Need to Figure Out Why String Functions Aren't Executing in My Conditionals

Tags: python, string, function, count, conditional-statements

Write a function called 'string_type' which accepts one
string argument and determines what type of string it is.

If the string is empty, return "empty".

If the string is a single character, return "character".

If the string represents a single word, return "word".
The string is a single word if it has no spaces.

If the string is a whole sentence, return "sentence".
The string is a sentence if it contains spaces, but at most one period.

If the string is a paragraph, return "paragraph". The
string is a paragraph if it contains both spaces and
multiple periods (we won't worry about other punctuation marks).

If the string is multiple paragraphs, return "page".
The string is a paragraph if it contains any newline
characters ("\n").

I'm allowed to use Python 3's built-in string functions (e.g., len, count, etc.)

I have been able to write a function with different conditions. At first, I tried doing conditions in the order outlined in the problem, however, I wasn't getting answers that matched my test case. I then reversed the order starting with a condition to check if the string is a page, then paragraph, etc.

```
def string_type(a_string):
    if a_string.count("\n") >= 1:
        return "page"
    elif a_string.count("") >= 1 and a_string.count(".") > 1:
        return "paragraph"
    elif len(a_string) > 1 and a_string.count("") > 1 and a_string.count(".") == 1:
        return "sentence"
    elif len(a_string) > 1 and a_string.count("") == 0:
        return "word"
    elif len(a_string) == 1:
        return "character"
    else:
        return "empty"
```

Below are some lines of code that will test your function.
You can change the value of the variable(s) to test your
function with different inputs.

## If your function works correctly, this will originally print

```
#empty
#character
#word
#sentence
#paragraph
#page

print(string_type(""))
print(string_type("!"))
print(string_type("CS1301."))
print(string_type("This is too many cases!"))
print(string_type("There's way too many ostriches. Why are there so many ostriches. The brochure said there'd only be a few ostriches."))
print(string_type("Paragraphs need to have multiple sentences. It's true.\nHowever, two is enough. Yes, two sentences can make a paragraph."))
```

When I run my current code, I get the following results:

```
#empty
#character
#sentence (instead of word)
#empty (instead of sentence)
#paragraph
#page
```

I have been tweaking both my word and sentence conditionals, however, I haven't figured out how to correct. Any explanation of what I did wrong and how to fix is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The places where you're searching for spaces in your string are wrong.

```
elif a_string.count("") >= 1
```

This will try to to find the empty sting `""` in the input - which it will obviously find.

That part (and others) should be:

```
elif a_string.count(" ") >= 1
```

Note it's `" "` - space.

Comment: thank you for the clarification on blank space, that does make a difference. When I re-write my code correcting for space, everything works except my instead of getting sentence for the one that is a sentence, I get empty. I am stumped figuring out why the condition doesn't execute.

Comment: You're talking about the 4th example right? That "sentence" ends with a `!` not a `.` - that's why you're getting empty

Comment: yes, I missed that initially. I corrected my conditional, and everything now works. Thanks again for your guidance!